# WSL Remote Connection Issue with VS Code

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use WSL on VS Code, but upon opening VS Code, I keep getting the following error messages:

Unable to detect if server is already installed: Error: Failed to probe if server is already installed: code: Failed to probe if server is already installed: code: 4294967295, , Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.

[2023-09-26 21:23:29.110] Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/0x80070569

I have tried addressing both error codes individually, and seemed to have some temporary success with code 4294967295 by trying several options:

uninstall and reinstall wsl ubuntu directly from microsoft store (rather than command line)

make sure my user is admin and has access

disable/reenable wsl by running powershell as admin and using the lines

DISM /online /disable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /norestart

DISM /online /disable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /norestart

and then enable-feature after restarting

reset winsock with netsh winsock reset

set hypervisor to start automatically with bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto

All of these fixes worked for about 24 hours or less, before returning to the same issue where I once again have to do one of those prompts and restart my computer. I really need a permanent solution so that I do not have to constantly restart my computer (I am using a Dell PC). Would greatly appreciate any help. My apologies if I am asking in the wrong place.

Comment: I think it would help to post this to [the WSL extension's issue tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues). (Yes, I know [a Microsoft employee told you to post this here or there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1377070/wsl-remote-connection-issue-with-vs-code)). Once you do, please ping me with a link to your issue ticket.